# Can't add Ksoap2 dependency to Android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, ksoap2

I have been trying to add ksoap2 to my android project. below is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
mavenCentral()

maven {
    url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'
}
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
}

dependencies {
compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
    exclude group: 'xmlpull'
}
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile ('com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.0.0')
}
```

The project compiles fine without errors, but when running the app on my device I get the below error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,   

:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preRele

aseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.485 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I have looked up almost every related question for such errors, but nothing works.
I have tried:

1) cleaning the project

2) adding

```
android {
dexOptions {
preDexLibraries = false
}
}
```

to my gradle file

3) adding

```
{
exclude group: 'xmlpull'
}
```

and a lot of other things, but nothing helps.
Also I created a new android project with just ksoap2 and it worked out. below is the working build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rsa.mobile.test_ksoap"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.0.0'
}
```

Its xstream and ksoap2 which are causing the issue when used together, but I have no clue on how to solve this. When used without each other my code works

Can someone please please help out. I have done everything I could till now with no luck at all.

Comment: I can see from the logs that: Download http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/org/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.3/xmlpull-1.1.3.3.jar  is getting downloaded. maybe this is the issue, but I dont know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution finally. We are supposed to add
exclude module: 'xmlpull' instead of exclude group: 'xmlpull' while adding the ksoap2 dependency.